Does a set of ground models and forcing extensions of a c.t.m. can make a tree (set theory)?
I think the set of all such models become a partially ordered set. For instance, I define $M_1 \leq M_2$ as $M_2$ is a forcing extension of $M_1$ or reversibly, $M_1$ is a ground model of $M_2$. Then, the reflexivity is satisfied because a model is clearly an extension of itself. The anti-symmetry also is fulfilled, if I close my eyes for that it is not 'equal' but 'isomorphic'. The transitivity is as well. On top of that, for each model $M$, the set $\{ N \in the \  set | N < M\}$ has a least element by DDG, proved recently. Unfortunately, this set is not total-order because there may be models, such that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are ground models of $M$ and these are not in such a relation.
Can we make some good trees in context of forcing extensions? Thanks in advance!
